# A static array is initialised in a while loop. can stack overflow happen in this case

Tags: c, linux

```
while(true)
{
   char array[1024] = {0};
   ....
   .....

}
```

I just want to know does stack over flow can happen in the above strip of code, or does the stack unwinds in every loop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your while loop has only char array[]? or does it have any other variables?

Comment: It has only a character array

Comment: No problem as far array has fixed size. [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) is a different story.

Answer (score 3):

The lifetime of an object with automatic storage duration is the block in which it was defined. The block in this case starts at the beginning of the while loop and ends at the end of it. So theoretically the object is reallocated every time we enter the loop.

In practice though, the compiler will just allocate enough space on the stack before the loop or even at the beginning of the function and just use that each time.

No chance of stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of `array` is limited to a particular iteration of the loop.

So yes, conceptually, a new `array` is created on each iteration, although a good compiler may well optimise this out if there are no side effects.

Whatever happens, there's no danger of a stack overflow error due to the repeated declaration and initialisation of `array`.